# Dryer vent issue - not enough vent to hook up hose

Tags: dryer, laundry

[image]As stated in the title - looking at my girlfriend's dryer/vent setup...realized she does not have a hose currently connected. Not great. The hole in the back wall (it's in her garage) barely has any vent protruding to clamp the hose to, and she said she's tried to do this with tape, etc, and it always falls off.

Any good tips for a vent piece that is barely giving anything to hook onto with a hose? I could remove the vent, I suppose, and slide in a vent with a longer pipe, then hook on a hose, or is there any type of good adapter to screw on over the barely existent vent pipe in the wall that I can then hook the hose into?

Thanks.

EDITED to add photo: Sorry the photo is kind of an angled shot, that is the wall, so should be vertical, with the other end of that vent pipe coming out the back wall of the house/garage area.

Comment: A picture would be incredibly useful.

Comment: Have you tried a [semi-rigid dryer duct](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-8-ft-Semi-Rigid-Dryer-Duct-WX08X10075/202214660) instead of the more common springy type that wants to rubber-band on you?

Comment: edited to add photo....

Answer (score 11):

I think you've got your answer right here:

> I could remove the vent, I suppose, and slide in a vent with a longer pipe, then hook on a hose

Of course, that may take more effort, but doing it the right way usually does. Up front. Once done correctly, it doesn't require the ongoing effort of fixing it again and again and again and...

Comment: I agree, I think this is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 6):

If the vent in the wall is female rigid dryer duct, poke the male (crimped) end of a rigid dryer duct or duct elbow **into** it. Fully stuffed in, it should friction-fit pretty well. If there's any sticking out from the wall you can also tape it, but friction-fit is generally fine since you should be cleaning it regularly anyway.

[image: Rigid dryer duct adjustable elboy - image from supplyhouse.com, no endorsement implied.]

If it's not the female end of a rigid dryer duct, then replacing the whole business with rigid dryer duct in the proper orientation is what you want to do **anyway**.

If you can manage to bother, the best way to hook up a dryer is with no hose at all. That requires some finagling to get the last bits of rigid duct connected when you put the dryer in place. The next-best method is to use as little hose as possible, so extending rigid duct towards the dryer vent is a *Good Thing®*

Comment: Hi - this is a great tip - however, it is not the female end, so again, I think replacing the whole thing is the way to go. I'll have to use some hose, but definitely know less is more when doing so...I'll replace duct and get this squared away...don't love the current "fire hazard" setup she has going on....  :)

Comment: Hi there...just added a photo (sorry, kind of at an angle). That is the wall actually behind the dryer, so should be vertical. You can see the pipe is barely sticking out, but is the crimped end of the vent pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation when I bought my house. Dryer in garage flexible dryer hose went into wall and up thru attic, and then up to vent on roof. EXCEPT, the part inside the wall was completely clogged and collapsed. Beyond a fire hazard. So I ran semi-ridgid tubing directly thru the ceiling, thru the attic and out the same roof vent. The only flex tube goes from the dryer to the semi-rigid. So easy to clean the vent out now too

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.